# How to switch View Controllers in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've looked all over Google & Stack Overflow, but I haven't found one clear answer. How do I switch to the TOCViewController after tapping the UIButton? I'm currently using "presentViewController" but it just freezes on tapping the button. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#import "SplashLoginViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "TOCViewController.h"

@interface SplashLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation SplashLoginViewController

- (void) displayTOC {
    TOCViewController *toc = [[TOCViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:toc animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)initializeSplashView
{
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    backgroundView.tag = 1;
    backgroundView.layer.zPosition = 99.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];

    UILabel *codeworksLabelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0 - 25.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50.0)];
    codeworksLabelView.text = @"Codeworks";
    codeworksLabelView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    codeworksLabelView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    codeworksLabelView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:30.0];
    codeworksLabelView.tag = 2;
    codeworksLabelView.layer.zPosition = 100.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:codeworksLabelView];
}

- (void)initializeLoginView
{
    CGRect loginFrame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 100.0, 30.0);
    CGRect passwordFrame = CGRectMake(50.0, 180.0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 100.0, 30.0);

    UITextField *usernameInput = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    usernameInput.frame = loginFrame;
    usernameInput.placeholder = @"Username";
    usernameInput.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:15.0];
    usernameInput.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    usernameInput.tag = 3;
    usernameInput.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    UITextField *passwordInput = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    passwordInput.frame = passwordFrame;
    passwordInput.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordInput.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:15.0];
    passwordInput.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    passwordInput.tag = 4;
    passwordInput.secureTextEntry = YES;

    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 29.0, usernameInput.frame.size.width, 1.0);
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    CALayer *borderCopy = [CALayer layer];
    borderCopy.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 29.0, passwordInput.frame.size.width, 1.0);
    borderCopy.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    [usernameInput.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
    [passwordInput.layer addSublayer:borderCopy];

    [self.view addSubview:usernameInput];
    [self.view addSubview:passwordInput];

    UILabel *signInButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, self.view.bounds.size.width, 60.0)];
    signInButton.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:15.0];
    signInButton.text = @"Sign In";
    signInButton.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    signInButton.tag = 5;
    signInButton.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    CALayer *topButtonBorder = [CALayer layer];
    topButtonBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1);
    topButtonBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    CALayer *bottomButtonBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomButtonBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 59, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1);
    bottomButtonBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    [signInButton.layer addSublayer:topButtonBorder];
    [signInButton.layer addSublayer:bottomButtonBorder];

    [self.view addSubview:signInButton];

    UIView *optionsDivide = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height - 45, 1, 20)];
    optionsDivide.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:optionsDivide];

    UIButton *tos = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIButton *pp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    tos.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 115.5 , self.view.bounds.size.height - 65, 110, 60);
    pp.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 + 0.5 , self.view.bounds.size.height - 65, 110, 60);

    [tos setTitle:@"Terms of Service" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pp setTitle:@"Privacy Policy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    pp.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    tos.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
    pp.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];

    [tos addTarget:self action:@selector(displayTOC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:tos];
    [self.view addSubview:pp];

}

- (void)animateSplashScreen
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view viewWithTag:2].frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0 - 25.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self initializeLoginView];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                               delay:1.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              [self.view viewWithTag:1].frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 65.0);
                                              [self.view viewWithTag:2].frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 15.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50.0);

                                              ((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2]).transform = CGAffineTransformScale(((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2]).transform, 0.6, 0.6);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              ((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2]).font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:30.0];

                                          }];
                     }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeSplashView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self animateSplashScreen];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    //CGPoint viewPoint = [[self.view viewWithTag:5] convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self.view];
    //if ([[self.view viewWithTag:5] pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event]) {
    //   [self.view viewWithTag:5].frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 62.5, 254.5, 130.0, 60.0);
    //}
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //[self.view viewWithTag:5].frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 67.5, 249.5, 130.0, 60.0);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //[self.view viewWithTag:5].frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 67.5, 249.5, 130.0, 60.0);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: To answer this question, I need to know if you are using a .storyboard file in your project.

Comment: @DanielT. I don't think I am. I have a storyboard but it's empty, as I've added all the elements programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy-pasted your code into a file and found a warning on this line `[tos addTarget:self action:@selector(displayTOC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` The warning says,

> Undeclared selector 'displayTOC:'

When I ran the code and tapped the TOC button, it didn't just freeze, it crashed with the error:

> -[ViewController displayTOC:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

These should be strong hints on what is wrong in your code. When you ask people about your code, you should reveal any and all warnings, and crashes.

Note, a method named `displayTOC` is not the same as a method named `displayTOC:`

By the way, the animation you did is really cool. Good job!

Comment: It's probably pretty obvious by now that I'm fairly new to iOS. Could you elaborate more on how to fix it? Do I just remove the colon? Also, thanks, I really like the animation too.

Comment: I just tried removing the colon and it worked. Thanks!